# Could we connect indirectly from iPad wifi to MobileFirst Server with security layer in the middle?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm able to connect from iPad wifi to mfp server in VSIT environment to MFP8.0 successfully. This is done by setting the mfpclient.plist to http://x.x.x.x:9080... besides, we are able to open the MobileFirst operation console from safari via http://x.x.x.x:9080/mfpconsole.

On the other hand, in SIT environment, we have a F5 security and OHS security layer in between the iPad wifi and mfp 8.0 server..  we've opened the context path for "mfp" runtime and "mfpconsole" in F5 security settings. We've set the mfpclient.plist to the F5 path https://y.y.y.y instead of the actual mfp 8.0 IP which is http://z.z.z.z:9080. Although we are able to open the MobileFirst operation console from safari via https://y.y.y.y/mfpconsole, we couldn't connect to the mfp8.0 server from the iPad app.

Questions:

1) Is this the formal/proper way to add security in IBM Mobile First?

2) What's the tutorial link or documentation for this kind of setup?

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is similar to the following in the documentation: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/using-mobilefirst-cli-to-manage-mobilefirst-artifacts/#configure-an-application

In order to register an application to a MobileFirst Server with a certain address, but also have the application connect to a different server address, for example a DataPower appliance (instead of datapower think it's your F5 appliance):

1. Run `mfpdev app register` to register the application in the expected MobileFirst Server address.
2. Run `mfpdev app config` and change the server property’s value to match the address of the DataPower appliance (or F5...). You can also run the command in direct mode: `mfpdev app config server http(s)://server-ip-or-host:port`.

I think this may work here.

F5 is a load balancer of sorts, it should be configured to do a redirection to the MobileFirst Server.